# PHP in JavaScript brokes all scripts

Tags: javascript, php, comments

When I'm using PHP in JavaScript, then all scripts don't work...
Even if I use php in comment.

```
<script> 
//var variable = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['abc']); ?>; 
</script>
```

This comment above destroy all scripts in `<script></script>` tags.
When I'll delete this line with the comment, then every script will work.
The same thing is when I just want to use PHP in JavaScript (without comment).
Could You help me ?

Here is code which was cut by me (to give You only necessary part of code), please help :) :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $validation = true;

        $firstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_SESSION['lastName'];
        $street = $_SESSION['street'];
        $phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];


        require_once "connect.php"; 

        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 

        try
        {
            $connection = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
            if($connection->connect_errno!=0)
            {
                throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
            else
            {
                if ($validation == true) // when validation process will be successfuly done - i cut validation process
                {
                    if($connection->query("INSERT INTO users values (NULL, '$firstName', '$lastName', '$street', '$phone', '$login', '$password', '$email')"))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['abc'] = "done";
                        //here is also header(location) to login page
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception($connection->error);
                    }
                }
                $connection->close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo '<div class="error">error. sorry, please to register in other term</div>';
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script>
//there are other functions for local/session storage

function deleteSessionData()
{
        var variable = "<?php echo $_SESSION['abc']; ?>";

            if(variable == "done")
            {
                sessionStorage.removeItem('firstName');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('lastName');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('street');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('phone');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('login');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('password');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('email');
            }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="myForm" method="post">
                    <label for="login">Login: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="login" name="login">
                    <label for="password">Password: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="password" name="password">
                    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                    <button onclick="java script: document.getElementById('myForm').submit();deleteSessionData();">Register</button>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: //var variable = "<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['abc']); ?>";

Comment: I can't see how this would end up creating invalid JS. There's no input you can give to `json_encode` that would result in a line-break in the output (without using pretty-print), so this should always end up as a single-line comment in the JS source. What is actually in `$_SESSION['abc']`?

Comment: Actually I don't want to comment this line. I just was wondering why even with comment it is still "spoils" my scripts. I wrote another answer under the first one with the actual problem :P

Comment: Have you got `display_errors` turned on? If `$_SESSION['abc']` is undefined then it'll be raising a notice, and if you're echoing that to the page then it would break your scripts. In any case, unless you show us *the source that this code is actually generating*, it's very hard for us to help you.

Comment: I think i don't have this option turned on. Ok I'll cut the unnecessary parts of the code and send it here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to comment the php too

```
//var variable = <?php // echo json_encode($_SESSION['abc']); ?>;
```

I wouldn't inject PHP into javascript like this without sanitation though.

Comment: `json_encode` already wraps quotes around string variables, adding extra ones will create a syntax error (assuming the line is uncommented at some point)